# Problem when calling decorator with arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to test the decorator test_params below for an unittest, but when I try to call it in the function test_testparams, I get an error:

```
TypeError: wrapper() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Is it because it is expecting self ?

```
import unittest
import functools


def test_params(kwargs_lst):
    '''allows to parametrise tests easily using a decorator'''

    def decorator(fn):
        @functools.wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(self):
            for kwargs in kwargs_lst:
                fn(self, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator


TEST_PARAMS_ARGS = [
    {'arg1': 1, 'arg2': None, 'arg3': "test"},
]

RECORDER = []


class TestParamsClass(object):
    def record_args(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        RECORDER.append({'arg1': arg1, 'arg2': arg2, 'arg3': arg3})


class DecoratorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_testparams(self):
        obj = TestParamsClass()

        decorated_fn = test_params(TEST_PARAMS_ARGS)(obj.record_args)
        decorated_fn()
        print("RECORDED:{}".format(RECORDER))
```

For full disclosure, I have already tried passing the self argument:

```
decorated_fn(obj)
```

but this will give this error:

```
TypeError: record_args() got multiple values for keyword argument 'arg1'
```

I tried as well using:

```
from functools import partial
decorated_fn = test_params(TEST_PARAMS_ARGS)(partial(obj.record_args, self=obj))
```

This gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

The reason there is a self argument is that it is normally used in test functions to pass arguments and the test function is inside an unittest.TestCase.

Comment: Well, you call `decorated_fn()`, without passing an argument for the expected `self` parameter…

Comment: @deceze, can you provide an example, I tried putting obj for self and could not make it work. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Why did you put `self` in there? I mean, shouldn't it just be `def wrapper()`, without any argument? Executing `fn` shouldn't take `self` as well - self is only relevant in classes, where functions are methods, so they are executed on some self object - when you do `obj.record_args`, you're already giving the function that has `self` set.

Comment: the reason I have self is that it is normally used in functions insides tests to pass test arguments as kwargs, I will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with [what Python methods really are](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod).

Normally you would apply the decorator to the function in the class declaration, ie:

```
class TestParamsClass(object):
    @test_params(TEST_PARAMS_ARGS)
    def record_args(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        RECORDER.append({'arg1': arg1, 'arg2': arg2, 'arg3': arg3})
```

in which case `test_params` (or more exactly the inner `decorator` function) will receive the `record_args` **function** as argument. But here:

```
decorated_fn = test_params(TEST_PARAMS_ARGS)(obj.record_args)
```

what you're passing is a `Method` object (cf the link above), which `__call__` method will already inject `obj` as the `self` argument when calling `record_args()` function.

If your `test_param` decorator is supposed to be used exclusively on methods (or, more exactly, on functions that will only be used as methods), you can change you test to decorate the method's function instead:

```
decorated_fn = test_params(TEST_PARAMS_ARGS)(obj.record_args.__func__)
```

and of course manually pass `obj` as argument:

```
decorated_fn(obj)
```

Else if you want to be able to use this decorator on both functions and methods, you can change the inner `wrapper` function signature from `self` to `*args` (and pass it along to `fn` so it can accomodate both situations.